# How can I reduce redirects in my Rails 3 web app?

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm new to Rails. I'm developing a store builder.

**What I want**

I want a root level url for each shop.

```
http://greatsite.com/my-shop-name
```

**My Solution**

**shop_controller.rb**

```
def show
    if params[:url]
     @shop_ref = params[:url]
     @shop = Shop.where(:url => @shop_ref).first
    else
     @shop_ref = params[:id]
     @shop = Shop.find(@shop_ref)
     redirect_to "/" + @shop.url 
     return
    end

    if @shop.nil?
     render 'show_invalid_shop', :object => @shop_ref and return
    end

    render 'show' =>  @shop
end

def create
    @shop_url = (0...8).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join.downcase
    @shop = Shop.new(:url => @shop_url)
    if @shop.save
        redirect_to "/" + @shop.url
    else
        render :action => "new"
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
...
resources :shops
match ':url' => 'shops#show', :constraints => { :url => /[a-z|0-9]{4,30}/ }
...
```

**The Problem**

Crap Performance. (It's ugly as sin too, of course.)

Every time someone creates a new shop (which is one click from our home page), it creates a new shop and does a redirect. In New Relic, I see this is killing performance - a lot of time is spent in "Request Queuing".

Is there any neater and faster way of achieving what I want?

Comment: How often are people creating new shops? It seems like the kind of action that happens infrequently enough for you to not care about performance. And you're doing things exactly right anyways. The `create` action should redirect to the `show` action on success. Performance shouldn't enter into it, it's a single http redirect on create.

Comment: Thanks, meagar. I'm still learning loads about Rails. It's good to know I'm doing the right thing. However, I should mention that on our site the very first thing a user does is create a shop. From Google Analytics, this action gets called for 82% of our traffic. And since we had a traffic spike of 32,000 uniques in 36 hours, this got a little messy! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the redirects would be causing such a headache, but:

Could you do something like:

- Create the shop via an AJAX call.
- On a successful create via AJAX render the show view, and return the html "string".
- Replace the contents of the page with JS, and use pushstate to update the URL.

Might be useful to look at: http://pjax.heroku.com/

It's not exactly pretty, but if redirects are really that bad it might help?

Comment: Love it. The thought had occurred to me since I put this post up, but I didn't know how to update the URL without reloading the page (which is what document.location('new_url') does in jquery) I came across pjax just the other day - looks like just the ticket! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend this, as it violates the REST principle...

But you *could* have `create` call/render the `show` action after it's done it's object creation (just like you do with "new" when it fails). That would eliminate the redirect but still show the same content as if it had.

There's a lot of reasons why you wouldn't want to do this. I'd look for performance improvements in other places first.